# How to bind change event for checkbox in knockout js?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm using bootstrap switch to show checkbox as a switch and I want to bind a function to this switch, so the `click` data bind does not help here because the checkbox is not being clicked.
So I probably need a "change" data bind like the `onChange` event that the checkbox have, but it didn't work when I tried to data bind `change` event to the checkbox...

Here is my data bind:

```
<input type="checkbox" onText="Active" offText="Inactive" 
       data-bind="bootstrapSwitchOn: ActiveFlag, change: function() { UpdateStatus() }" />
```

The switch is renders the checkbox like this:

```
<div class="has-switch" tabindex="0"
     <div class="switch-on">
          <span class="switch-left">Active</span
          <label>&nbsp;</label
          <span class="switch-right">Inactive</span>
          <input type="checkbox" ontext="Active" offtext="Inactive"
                 data-bind="bootstrapSwitchOn: ActiveFlag, change: function() { UpdateStatus() }">
     </div>
</div>
```

The checkbox gets `display:"none"` so it is not clicked but its state does change when clicking the switch

Comment: Have you tried `event: { change: function() { UpdateStatus() } }`?

Comment: Cool, it works :-) Can you please add it as an answer so that I could mark it as answered ?

Comment: But the event is fired twice instead of only once now

Comment: How about subscribing to `ActiveFlag`?  `var x = this.ActiveFlag.subscribe(this.UpdateStatus);`

Comment: I assume the `change` event is fired both by Knockout and BootstrapSwitch. Can you create a Fiddle?

Comment: Anish, I am not familiar with this context. Can you please tell me where to include it ?

haim, I can't create a Fiddle because my code invovles some dll's with grid views and it is more complex

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31499813/how-to-bind-change-event-for-checkbox-in-knockout-js#comment50963738_31499813):

1. You have an *observable* called `ActiveFlag` bound to the `bootstrapSwitchOn` binding which is updated when the *bootstrap switch* is toggled.
2. And *Knockoutjs* has the facility to allow you to register callbacks to changes on *observables*.

With the these to points in mind, if you have an *observable* that is bound to changes to your toggle and you want to call some function when this toggle changes then you can register a your function as a callback to listen to the changes of the *observable*.

Hopefully, this snippet can explain this logic:

```js
/**
 * Knockout binding handler for bootstrapSwitch indicating the status
 * of the switch (on/off): https://github.com/nostalgiaz/bootstrap-switch
 */
ko.bindingHandlers.bootstrapSwitchOn = {
  init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
    $elem = $(element);
    $(element).bootstrapSwitch();
    $(element).bootstrapSwitch('setState', ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor())); // Set intial state
    $elem.on('switch-change', function(e, data) {
      valueAccessor()(data.value);
    }); // Update the model when changed.
  },
  update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
    var vStatus = $(element).bootstrapSwitch('state');
    var vmStatus = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
    if (vStatus != vmStatus) {
      $(element).bootstrapSwitch('setState', vmStatus);
    }
  }
};

// your viewmodel bound to the web page

var vm = function() {
  this.log = ko.observableArray([]);

  // ActiveFlag observable bound to switch, synced with state of switch
  this.ActiveFlag = ko.observable(false);

  // the function I want to call whenever the switch state changes
  var doSomethingWhenSwitchStateChanges = function(value) {
    this.log.push('the switch state changed to: ' + value);
  }.bind(this);

  // register callback
  var subscription = this.ActiveFlag.subscribe(doSomethingWhenSwitchStateChanges);

}

ko.applyBindings(new vm());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-switch/2.0.0/css/bootstrap-switch.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-switch/2.0.0/js/bootstrap-switch.min.js"></script>


<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: ActiveFlag" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox" data-bind="bootstrapSwitchOn: ActiveFlag" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6" data-bind="foreach: log">
    <p data-bind="text: $data"><p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: My switch is inside a custom grid view and I can launch my function but it fires twice insted of once...

Comment: Have you tried to hook your function into the `ActiveFlag` observable instead of the `change` binding? Does it still fire twice?

Comment: In your solution, how can I pass the `$data` to the function ? I want to use more data in addition to the `ActiveFlag`

Comment: @LiranFriedman You have access to the view and its scope from the function in my example. Was there anything in particular outside of the view model scope you wanted access to?

Comment: I'm accessing it from a grid view and I need the entire row data because clicking the checkbox goes to the server with this data.

Comment: @LiranFriedman ok I understand. Can you please post the code of your view model and whatever else is bound to the grid so I get get a better idea of your setup.

Comment: I've just added a click counter to avoid kaunching the function twice...
Thank you very much for your help :-)